# IBM Watson Assistant: How to read data from an AWS MySQL table and determine dialogue based on the data (Yes or No)?

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

We have an AWS MySQL users table that has a column (flag) to indicate if the user is a paid member or not (Yes or No).

Can IBM Watson Assistant on IBM Cloud read the data, given the user ID, and depending on whether it's Yes or No, proceed to a different dialogue sequence?

Do you have an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to reach out to database systems from within an IBM Watson Assistant dialog. For an example including code see this [IBM Cloud solution tutorial on building a database-driven Slackbot](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson#build-a-database-driven-slackbot).

[Watson Assistant supports so-called programmatic](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-actions#dialog-actions) calls from within a dialog node. It allows to either signal the calling application to perform some action or to invoke an IBM Cloud Functions action. In the mentioned tutorial Cloud Functions is used to to reach out to a database system to retrieve or insert data.

In your case, you would write an IBM Cloud Functions action, would need to bind the credentials, and then, in the chatbot dialog, invoke that action to check for the member status.

Comment: Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: Please upvote and, if it solved it, mark as answered